# Timing issues in multiple SELECT statements in transaction

Tags: mysql, sql

My question is about the timing of SELECT queries in a transaction. I am wondering if multiple SELECT statements will return data as it was at the beginning of the transaction or if they will return values as they are when the query is executed. In the latter case, this would be a problem if an other process modifies some tables. Here's an example, where the steps are done sequentially by 2 processes:

```
+------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------+
|                      Process 1                       |           Process 2            |
+------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------+
| query("START TRANSACTION");                          |                                |
| $res1 = query("SELECT foo1 FROM table1 FOR UPDATE"); |                                |
|                                                      | $res = query("UPDATE table2"); |
| $res2 = query("SELECT foo2 FROM table2 FOR UPDATE"); |                                |
| doSomeStuff($res1, $res2)                            |                                |
| query("COMMIT");                                     |                                |
+------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------+
```

In the example, the function `doSomeStuff($res1, $res2)` requires the data to have been gathered at the same time, to represent a coherent snapshot of the database. Is this the case? If not, what would be a proper way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: it depends on what your default isolation level is.

Comment: _isolation level_ is the term I was missing in my search. Thanks @TMcKeown